# MySQL character encoding change. Is data integrity preserved?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, data-integrity

I will have to convert the database encoding from latin-1 to utf-8.

I'm aware of the fact that converting the database is done via the command of

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [[DEFAULT] COLLATE collation_name]
```

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-database.html) and converting an existing table is done via the command of

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [COLLATE collation_name]
```

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-table.html).

However, the database is already existent and there is sensitive information involved. My question is whether the data I already have will be changed. The purpose of this question is that I have to give an estimate before I do the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every (character string-type) **column** has its *own* character set and collation metadata.

If, when the **column**'s data type was specified (i.e. when it was last created or altered), no character set/collation was explicitly given, then the table's default character set and collation would be used for the column.

If, when the **table** was specified, no default character set/collation was explicitly given, then the database's default character set and collation would be used for the table's default.

The commands that you quote in your question merely alter such default character sets/collations for the database and table respectively.  In other words, they will only affect tables and columns that are created thereafter—they will **not** affect existing columns (or data).

To update existing data, you should first read the [Changing the Character Set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-character-set) section of the manual page on `ALTER TABLE`:

> #### Changing the Character Set
>
> To change the table default character set and all character columns ([`CHAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html), [`VARCHAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html), [`TEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html)) to a new character set, use a statement like this:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
> ```
>
> The statement also changes the collation of all character columns. If you specify no `COLLATE` clause to indicate which collation to use, the statement uses default collation for the character set. If this collation is inappropriate for the intended table use (for example, if it would change from a case-sensitive collation to a case-insensitive collation), specify a collation explicitly.
>
> For a column that has a data type of [`VARCHAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html) or one of the [`TEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) types, `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` changes the data type as necessary to ensure that the new column is long enough to store as many characters as the original column. For example, a [`TEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) column has two length bytes, which store the byte-length of values in the column, up to a maximum of 65,535. For a `latin1` [`TEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) column, each character requires a single byte, so the column can store up to 65,535 characters. If the column is converted to `utf8`, each character might require up to three bytes, for a maximum possible length of 3 × 65,535 = 196,605 bytes. That length does not fit in a [`TEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) column's length bytes, so MySQL converts the data type to [`MEDIUMTEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html), which is the smallest string type for which the length bytes can record a value of 196,605. Similarly, a [`VARCHAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html) column might be converted to [`MEDIUMTEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html).
>
> To avoid data type changes of the type just described, do not use `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET`. Instead, use `MODIFY` to change individual columns. For example:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE t MODIFY latin1_text_col TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
> ALTER TABLE t MODIFY latin1_varchar_col VARCHAR(M) CHARACTER SET utf8;
> ```
>
> If you specify `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET binary`, the [`CHAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html), [`VARCHAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html), and [`TEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) columns are converted to their corresponding binary string types ([`BINARY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/binary-varbinary.html), [`VARBINARY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/binary-varbinary.html), [`BLOB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html)). This means that the columns no longer will have a character set attribute and a subsequent `CONVERT TO` operation will not apply to them.
>
> If ***`charset_name`*** is `DEFAULT` in a `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` operation, the character set named by the [`character_set_database`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_database) system variable is used.
>
> > #### Warning
> >
> > The `CONVERT TO` operation converts column values between the original and named character sets. This is *not* what you want if you have a column in one character set (like `latin1`) but the stored values actually use some other, incompatible character set (like `utf8`). In this case, you have to do the following for each such column:
> >
> > ```
> > ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 BLOB;
> > ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
> > ```
> >
> > The reason this works is that there is no conversion when you convert to or from [`BLOB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) columns.
>
> To change only the *default* character set for a table, use this statement:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE tbl_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET charset_name;
> ```
>
> The word `DEFAULT` is optional. The default character set is the character set that is used if you do not specify the character set for columns that you add to a table later (for example, with `ALTER TABLE ... ADD column`).
>
> When the [`foreign_key_checks`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) system variable is enabled, which is the default setting, character set conversion is not permitted on tables that include a character string column used in a foreign key constraint. The workaround is to disable [`foreign_key_checks`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) before performing the character set conversion. You must perform the conversion on both tables involved in the foreign key constraint before re-enabling [`foreign_key_checks`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks). If you re-enable [`foreign_key_checks`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) after converting only one of the tables, an `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON UPDATE CASCADE` operation could corrupt data in the referencing table due to implicit conversion that occurs during these operations (Bug #45290, Bug #74816).

Comment: I have a list of [_fixes_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases) that goes beyond this answer.