# Chang MySQL character encoding of a running application

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, character-encoding, data-integrity

Fist of all, I've read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966750/mysql-character-encoding-change-is-data-integrity-preserved#:%7E:text=The%20commands%20that%20you%20quote,existing%20columns%20(or%20data).), which is very helpful, too; However, to be 100% sure of that the important data will not be mistakenly changed, I want to ask more specific questions.

Some backgrounds:

1. My company maintains a running application. It uses mysql and we set the DB on a AWS EC2 instance.
2. For some reason I go to check the data in the DB directly. I saw the following by run a SELECT command
   [image]
3. At the cell of 2nd row by column `code1`, it shows `?????`, but it shouldn't be. It should be some Japanese characters.
4. Below is the output after I run `show variables like 'char%';`
   [image]
5. Another colleague connects to the exactly same EC2 instance and DB. No encoding problem happens. There is no `?????` but the correct content.
6. The output of `show variables like 'char%';`, on that end, differs from mine by that there are all `utf8`, no `latin1`.
7. The system language of my mac is English, and on the other mac is Japanese.

My questions:

1. Do the mysql variables differ by each host connecting to the EC2 instance? I thought they are variables for the EC2 instance/the DB (so whoever connects to it should see the same values, but apparently it is not the case)
2. I guess if I change all the variables to `utf8` the encoding problem will disappear. But I don't want to try this casually, given the risk of ruining the data. Will this effect the existing data, if run only SELECT command after that? Do I have to change the variables back to `latin1` for the sake of data-integrity?
3. Given that this is a running application, even if I don't perform some CREATE or UPDATE commands, what if the end users have made some changed, after I change the mysql encoding variables? Will the new data added by the end user have encoding problem?

Comment: Edit .INI file used by your client, its command line and/or connection properties and set utf8 using. Additionally - look at SHOW CREATE TABLE for your table - I think that the column/table charset is defined as utf8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)